# Is there anything like D3's Nest functionality in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, d3.js

Nesting means taking an array of key value pairs and grouping them hierarchically by a specified key. See this page for examples: http://bl.ocks.org/d/3176159/. If not, I'll just try to port https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/core/nest.js over but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: It would be useful if we didn't have to go through the code trying to find out what it does because you **told it us.**

Comment: Good point! I added some explanation and a link to examples.

Comment: Thanks! Well, for the record, I don't know anything that does this instantly. You can, however, reimplement it fairly easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer that I came up with. Let me know if you have suggestions for improvements.

```
// Wrapper method
// keys are in order of hierarchy
- (NSMutableArray *)nestArray:(NSArray *)array withKeys:(NSArray *)keys
{
    return [self nestArray:array withKeys:keys depth:0];
}

// Private
// Assumes arrays of dictionaries with strings as the entries.
- (NSMutableArray *)nestArray:(NSArray *)array withKeys:(NSArray *)keys depth:(int)depth
{
    // Current key
    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:depth];
    depth++;

    // Create dictionary of the keys
    NSMutableDictionary *map = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array) {
        NSString *value = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
        if ([map objectForKey:value]) {
            [[map objectForKey:value] addObject:dictionary];
        } else {
            [map setObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:dictionary] forKey:value];
        }
    }

    NSMutableArray *nest = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString *valkey in [map allKeys]) {
        NSMutableArray *values = [map objectForKey:valkey];
        if (depth < keys.count) {
            values = [self nestArray:[NSArray arrayWithArray:array] withKeys:keys depth:depth];
        }
        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:valkey,@"key",values,@"values", nil];
        [nest addObject:dictionary];
    }

    return nest;
}
```